# JS Bin Warning: Bad escapement of EOL. Use option multistr if needed

Tags: javascript, jsbin

That is a warning stemming from snippets like:

```
a="hello\
world"
```

Apparently JsBin does not support the line continuation character unless a specific option is set.

How to set the mentioned multi-string option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't know if you need this anymore, but use: `/*jshint multistr: true */`

Example:

```
/*jshint multistr: true */
var data = "multiline \
text \
here.";
```

It will simply remove warning.